# Vuetify v-progress-circular not changing colors with color prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

For some reason my `v-progress-circular` component is not changing colors with the `color prop`.

```html
<v-progress-circular
  class="loader"
  v-if="loading"
  :size="70"
  :width="7"
  color="yellow"
  indeterminate
 ></v-progress-circular>
```

But if I wrap it in a div and add the color style it works.

```html
<div style="color:yellow;">
   <v-progress-circular
      class="loader"
      v-if="loading"
      :size="70"
      :width="7"
      color="yellow"
      indeterminate
   ></v-progress-circular>
</div>
```

Not sure what's wrong with the prop.

Comment: What color is it showing up as? Is it wrapped inside another tag that has a style prop with a color set? Your code works fine, there is just something that is overwriting it somewhere else.

Comment: There is nothing wrapping it, but the app does have a dark theme. I'm not sure if that has any precedence over the color. The color of the component is black.

Comment: What's the resulting HTML look like?
Does it apply `yellow--text` on the element?

Comment: Are you applying some color in the loader class maybe?
I just replicated your example [here](https://codepen.io/bcakmakoglu/pen/eYWrmBd?editors=111) and it really works fine, dark mode or not.

Comment: So I realized that the v-app component was not a parent of the progress component. That fixed it.  I'm not sure why the component would work outside of v-app, but something like the color prop wouldn't. Sorry guys, I'm still fairly new to vue.